# Как записать в cookie присвоенный элементу класс

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Нашел несколько статей по работе с `cookie`, все они описывали какие-то сложные случаи в итоге мало что понял. Мне же сейчас этого не нужно, хочу начать совсем с простого:

Как присвоить блоку класс, а после перезагрузки страницы класс должен остаться?

```js
$("input").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.block').toggleClass('active')
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #4DB6AC;
}
.block.active {
  background: #FFC107;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<input type='button' value='Переключатель'>
```

также прочитал, что `cookie` сохраняются только на одну сессию,

1. как сделать чтобы они хранились там до тех пор пока пользователь сам
   не почистит браузер?
2. Как делать чтобы `cookie` хранились 24 часа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вопрос 1.**
При установке куков можно задать им параметр `expires`. Тогда они проживут столько, сколько Вы им скажете, если конечно сервер не перепишет.

Если указать дату в прошлом, то кука будет удалена сразу. Если не указать, кука считается сесионной и при закрытии браузера тухнет.

Вы не можете посмотреть когда кука истекает через js. Но можете через консоль разработчика. В chrome это на вкладке "Resources"

Бесконечные куки задать нельзя, но можно сказать им жить пару лет, это вам хватит за глаза.

Подробнее можете прочитать [например здесь](http://learn.javascript.ru/cookie)

**Вопрос 2.**
Что-то вроде того:

```
var now, expirationDate = new Date(), 
    newCookie;

 // Страшное число - это один день в миллисекундах. 
 expirationDate.setTime(now.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);

 newCookie = "myCookie=testCookieValue;expires=" + expirationDate.toUTCString();
 document.cookie = newCookie;
```

**Пункт 3.**
Куки надо использовать для данных, которые должен знать сервер. В случае если это информация которая серверу не нужна совсем, следует использовать `localStorage` или `sessionStorage`. Данные в `sessionStorage` живут браузерную сессию. Данные в `localStorage` живут пока их не убьют принудительно. То есть параметра `expirationDate` для `localStorage` нету, его можно реализовать самому при желании.

У стораджей есть функции `setItem(key, value)` и `getItem(key, value)` с помощью которых вы можете доставать и убирать в них значения.

**То есть для решения вашей основной задачи:**
К моменту когда загрузится ваш элемент (onLoad) нужно проверять данные которые хранятся в сторадже и навешивать в зависимости от них нужный класс.
Когда Вы переключаете класс на элементе, вам соответственно надо менять значение и в хранилище.

Comment: А на самый главный вопрос ответ дать сможете?) ему для него и написал код, а 2 вопроса это как дополнение к основному)

Comment: то есть если я переключил класс у элемента он должен записываться в  localStorage?? и из этого localStorage браузер должен извлекать данные о состоянии элемента?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, ну в общем Вы правильно сказали что надо делать, релазиацию оставляю вам. Отличие localStorage и sessionStorage ot cookie помимо того что куки едут на сервер и размера в том, что для storage надо expirationDate руками писать, если вам нужно.

Comment: сейчас, задам тогда новый вопрос, все-таки есть непонятные моменты.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, прям код мне сейчас за вас лень писать, потому что jsFiddle со стораджами не работает, а на ноутбуке у меня ничгео кроме блокнота не стоит)

Comment: да может быть сейчас сам разберусь)) мне главное чтобы вообще работало, а что на jsFiddle  не работает это понятно)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/530644/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-localstorage-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE