# Работа с localStorage. Как сделать, чтобы присвоенный блоку класс, сохранился после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Как присвоить блоку класс (но после перезагрузки страницы класс должен остаться)?
Сначала думал, что нужно использовать куки, но посоветовали `localStorage`.
Прочитал, понял как извлекать из `localStorage` данные, но так и не понял, как объяснить и записать в localStorage, что например блоку присвоен или удален класс, и прикреплять этот класс если он записан в `localStorage`.

Написал, ниже код, но даже не знаю степень его ошибочности.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('block')= true) {
    $('.block').addClass('active');
  }
});
$("input").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.block').toggleClass('active');
  if (localStorage.getItem('block') = true) {
    localStorage.removeItem("block", "active");
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("block", "active");
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #4DB6AC;
}
.block.active {
  background: #FFC107;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<input type='button' value='Переключатель'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала нужно исправить очевидные ошибки "=" это не тоже самое, что "==".

Вот [ваш код на codepen](http://codepen.io/diproart/pen/bedMKz), который работает.

```
...
if (localStorage.getItem('block') == 'active') {
  $('.block').addClass('active');
}
...
```

p.s. И внимательно изучать основы JavaScript.